# How to update a Windows Azure Worker Role while running

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a single instanced Worker Role up and running. Now I want to update the Worker Role via RDP without redeploying (for testing issues). How can I do this?

(I know that the local changes are lost if the VM will be recycled)

**Edit**: I simply want to replace the running code on the worker role like it works with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you kind of answer your own question?  RDP?  Or are you asking how to get RDP working?

Comment: He's probably asking as to what location to update and how to do it while the process is running.  I am not sure this is possible as stopping of the WorkerRole process recycles the instance.

Comment: No, I am online with RDP, no problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is actually pretty simple :)

http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/

You get the "Deploy" functionality of VS to work with an azure deployment. It is useful in some situations. You get a template for the deployment & a really sexy application manager along with the publish endpoint that you can use VS with. Really cool, to be honest. I'd use it, but I need the local resources etc., to work too...

One more [blog post explaining](http://ntotten.com/2011/07/windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles/) how it works.

Comment: Just one more addition, I know you are asking about worker roles. I'd use the concept behind this implementation and work in a "dynamic" loading of the worker role. But this is your best bet.

Comment: Ok. So it seems that I have to use the upgrade button (portal) if I want to deploy my Worker Role. 
see **Edit**.

Comment: Well, depending on how much effort you want to invest. You could get away with some custom... but it boils down to how much time you have.

Comment: Seems that I have to live with redeploying. Anyway, Thanks.